# Finding someone willing to train programming in a certain area

Tags: support

Is there a way on Stack Overflow or here on meta to find people willing to train a programming language in a certain town or city?

After searching extensively on google and many different websites ive not been able to track down a tutor in Doncaster or nearby to teach me ASP.net and C# on a weekend.

Is it acceptable to post this kind of question on here or Stack Overflow?

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Comment: [Down-votes are different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: Wow really? Another one? I thought the whole point of meta was to ask these sorts of questions. Not get down voted for asking a legitimate question that i would like an answer for. :/

Comment: Read the link from ChrisF's comment... Don't be discouraged...

Comment: Have you considered [online courses?](https://www.google.com/search?q=asp.net+online+courses)

Comment: I have not really to be honest @Lix It may be something i can look at in the future. Thanks for the input. But no thanks to everyone else who downvoted. You have really put me off participating in any way on meta.

Comment: @Sam - did you see the links about how voting on meta works differently?

Comment: Yes but i dont think the question warranted such "disagreement" as it is put in the FAQ. All the question warranted was an answer stating if this was acceptable and if not what would be the best way of approaching this. It did not deserve 6 downvotes.

Comment: @Sam, there was nothing wrong with your post.  No spelling mistakes, it was **on** topic - you were correct to post it here.  However I believe that that downvotes were from users who felt like there is no place in [so] for posts requesting *tutors*.  Speaking from my own opinion I wouldn't like to see a post/chat message requesting me to tutor someone - this is simply not the right site for that.

Comment: That is the whole reason why i asked. Perhaps by giving that as an answer would have been the better course of action. I will not be participating in meta again because of the unfriendliness of what seems like the majority of people on here.

Comment: Sam, I'm sorry you feel that way but Meta is a place for people to voice their opinions: you voiced yours, and other people voiced theirs. People disagree with your idea about having tutors. I don't think people like @Lix or voters were unfriendly, rather they were just using their opportunity to state their piece

Answer (score 11):

Not on Stack Overflow itself.

You might want to ask in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com)